# Outlook 365 - Cannot confirm security alert for self-signed certificate

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, certificate, email-client, email-server

I use Outlook on a few of my machines with my own email server in the backend. This email server is used with a self signed certificate which I am using for about 5 years. To this point I was able to accept the certificate by clicking "Yes" in the dialog shown here:

[image: Outlook Security Alert - Self Signed Cert]

About 2 weeks ago, on one of my machines, this "Yes" button started to be greyed out which prevents me from connecting to the server completely. On other machines this functionality still works.

**what I tried so far**

- Validated the certificate. It is valid but self-signed
- I removed office 365 from the impacted machine and reinstalled it. -> no change, "Yes" still greyed out
- Deleted the email account and set it up again -> no change, "Yes" still greyed out
- Clicked "View certificate" and installed the certificate on the impacted machine  -> no change, "Yes" still greyed out

**what I have not tried yet**

- Walk through the registry and delete every entry that contains outlook after uninstalling office 365
- reinstall windows on the impacted machine

Is there anyone who can tell me what I need to do to get this field accessible again so I can use Outlook as usual?

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in [this article](https://www.dalesandro.net/using-self-signed-s-mime-certificates-in-outlook/)?

Comment: @harrymc I have not yet but will try that tonight. The reason I am not sure there will be a positive outcome is that on other computers Outlook still works fine. Just not on this one machine. Anyway I will try tonight and provide an update.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the article you posted @harrymc. Unfortunately, without any success. I still cannot click the "yes" button as it is still greyed out. I also went into the registry, as suggested by a removed answer, to add a registry key. That process also did not work.
What I just can't wrap my head around is that on another computer with the same software version (Win10, Outlook) it works just on this one laptop it does not. Anyway. Any other ideas?